# Model.find().sort() returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
let query = Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));


if (req.query.sort) {
  query = query.sort(req.query.sort);//a string 'ratings'
}


const tours = await query;

res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  requestedAt: req.requestTime,
  result: tours.length,
  data: {
    tours,
  },
});
```

this is my code here tours should return me all the data but it's just giving me a empty array. I'm new to all of this and i can't find a solution but i know for sure something is happening in the sort method I'm using cause i used the debugger and i can't understand what's happening inside there.

I'm using mongoose v5 and node is v18 i don't know if that's the problem so if someone can help me out it would be great

Comment: please show the `query find()` as well and what is the value of `req.query.sort`

Comment: Where are you specifying which database to use?

Comment: your code has no `something.find().sort()` anywhere in it. There's only has `thing.sort()`. Did you forget the actual `find()` code?

Comment: Is the result still empty if you remove the `.sort()`? Perhaps whatever you're passing in `queryStr` isn't matching any documents

Comment: If I am not mistaken, find(..) returns Promise, not actual value. So, either rewrite via Promises or  use async/await

Comment: @VasylMoskalov no, it returns a query object (which can be implicitly executed by `await`ing it)

Comment: @Bergi just guessing here, but how about trying `await query.exec()` instead of `await query`? What I'm guessing is that the await now doesn't actually perform the query and you are getting an array as a default JSON transformation of a non-executed query. I know you said the issue is with sort, but can't hurt to test, right? :)

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I said nothing about what the issue is, but no, `await query` will implicitly execute it through the `.then()` method. Also `query` is an object not an array.

Comment: @Bergi my apologies, meant to tag OP and not you! You are right :) I was thinking if the Mongoose Query class would have overrided the default JSON conversion; something like `class Foo{toJSON() { return "[]"} } console.log(JSON.stringify(new Foo()))` but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to be a comment. When debugging this, try hardcoding the feature first and then adding dynamic values.

I just tried recreating what you have and it works fine, so the problem is probably in your value for `queryStr` or `req.query.sort`. Below is my test setup

```js
// Model
const Tour = mongoose.model('tours', new mongoose.Schema({
    ratings: Number,
    description: String,
}))

// Initial data
// const tour1 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 8, desc: "Bad" })
// const tour2 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 3, desc: "Bad" })
// const tour3 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 1, desc: "Cool" })
// const tour4 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 4, desc: "Bad" })
// const tour5 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 4, desc: "Cool" })
// const tour6 = await Tour.create({ ratings: 999, desc: "Cool" })

// Test
const query = Tour.find({desc: "Cool"})
query.sort("ratings")

const tours = await query
console.log({ tours })
```

This produced the expected output of only "Cool" tours sorted by rating. See how I used hardcoded values for sorting and finding? This leads me to believe that the issue is in the values.